# What are eigenvalues and eigenvectors of polynomial vector space?

Tags: polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $P_1$ be the vector space of the general polynomials of degree less than or equal to one and let $T: P_1 \rightarrow P_1$ be the linear transformation that takes the polynomial $1 + x$ to $5 + 2x$ and the polynomial $4 + x$ to $-2(4+x)$. What are the eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Comment: I tried editing your question to make it more readable. Is this what you were asking?

Comment: It is easiest to just transform the question to work with a square matrix, after choosing a basis into work in. Here I would probably just work in the monomial basis; to do that,  you need to find $T(1)$ and $T(x)$.

Comment: After your edit, my previous comment is somewhat invalidated. Now it is helpful to work in the $\{ 1+x,4+x \}$ basis, since it is easy to write $5+2x$ in terms of a combination of $1+x$ and $4+x$ and because $4+x$ is already given as an eigenvector.

Comment: @Ian The truth is i didnt understand how to work with polynomials when working eigens.. Do you have some material to indicate?
The book shows me how to solve, but i didnt understand..It says the Transformation Matriz is (1 1, 0 -2) and eigenvectors are v = 13a+4ax associated to eigenvalue = 1, v = 4b+bx associated do -2.

Comment: @FELINTONETO The matrix here sends $1+x$ to $5+2x=(1+x)+(4+x)$ and $4+x$ to $-2(4+x)$, so in the basis $\{ 1+x,4+x \}$ it is represented as $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & -2 \end{bmatrix}$. (In general the $i$th column of a matrix $A$ is the image of the $i$th basis vector, say $e_i$, under $A$.) You can then find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this and then just make the identification $e_1=1+x,e_2=4+x$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

1. $P_1$ in your example is like $\mathbb{R}^2$. Can you map your problem to vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$?
2. After (1), the linear transformation can be represented by a matrix, for which you know how it maps 2 vectors. Can you construct the matrix from the given 2 mappings?
3. Diagonalize the matrix as usual
4. Eigenvalues stay the same, can you map eigenvectors back to $P_1$ using the inverse of the map you used in (1)?